# Custom authentication in App engine Mobile Backend

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, authentication, mobile, backend

Currently Google Cloud Mobile Backend Starter requires all clients to sign-in using Google Account. There is any implementation of custom authentication mechanism?

Comment: http://chirashi.zenconsult.net/2013/07/custom-authentication-with-google-cloud-endpoints-using-app-engine-java/

Answer (score 0):

in Android client  in Consts.java set:

public static final boolean IS_AUTH_ENABLED = false;